# client websocket implementation

Tags: memory-leaks, websocket, mod-pywebsocket

I'm running a stress test and need to run many websocket clients on the same machine.

I don't think a normal implementation for web browser is a good idea for many clients and am looking for a way to be able to run them on console without browser.

There are many server implementations (I'm using pywebsocket) but for clients I just found the possibility of using Node.js which seems to have some memory leaks or that's what I've experienced.

Is there any other solution apart from node.js?
It would be great if it was possible to do it also with pywebsocket, but didn't find any clue on the internet so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [QWebSockets](http://kurtpattyn.github.io/QWebSockets/), which is an implementation in Qt/C++, both for clients and servers.
You can also have a look at http://autobahn.ws, which provides Python clients and servers, and also a test suite for WebSockets.